# Matlab Euler-explicit with adaptable step for ODE system

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, algorithms, matlab

I have the following system of differential equations (it is a simplified model for the activation of a neuron, but it is not really important for the question):
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = V - \frac{V^3}{3} - n^2 + I_{\text{app}}$$where $I_{\text{app}}$ is a function of time or a constant. And: 
$$\frac{dn}{dt} = 0.1\left(\frac{2}{1-\exp(-5V)}-n\right)$$
I want to solve this system using Euler's explicit method that I have to make myself and, also, using `ode45`.

I have done as follows:

```
function x = nagumo1(t, y, f)
Iapp = f(t);
e = 0.1;
F = 2/(1+exp(-5*y(1)));
n0 = 0;
x = zeros(1, 2);
x(1) = y(1) - (y(1).^3)/3 - y(2).^2 + Iapp;
x(2) = e.*(F + n0 - y(2));
end
```

which calculates the derivatives at time `t`, with initial conditions $y = [V, n]$

Now my function Euler Explicit is:

```
function x =  EulerExplicit1(V0, n0, tspan, Iapp)

format shorteng;

erreura = 10^-2;
erreurr = 10^-2;

h = 0.1;

to =tspan(1, 1) + h;
temps = to;
tf = tspan(1, 2);

y = zeros(1,2);
yt1 = zeros(1, 2);
yt2 = zeros(1, 2);
y = [V0, n0];

z = y;

i = 1;

s = zeros(1, 2);
st1 = zeros(1, 2);

for t = to:h:(tf - h)

   s = nagumo1(to+i*h, y, Iapp);
   y = y + h*s;
   yt1 = y + (h/2)*s;
   st1 = nagumo1(to+(i*h+h/2), yt1, Iapp);
   yt2 = yt1 + (h/2)*st1;

   if abs(yt2-y)>(erreura+erreurr*abs(y))
      test = 0;
   else
      h = h*2;
      test = 0;
   end

   while test == 0

      if abs(yt2-y)>(erreura+erreurr*abs(y)) & h>0.005
         h = h/2;
         s = nagumo1(to+i*h, y, Iapp);
         y = y + h*s;
         yt1 = y + (h/2)*s;
         st1 = nagumo1(to+i*h+h/2, yt1, Iapp);
         yt2 = yt1 + (h/2)*st1;
      else
         test = 1;
      end
   end

   temps(i)=to+i*h;
   z = [ z ; y ];
   i = i+1;

end

x = zeros(size(z));
x = z;

disp('Nombre d iterations:');

disp(i);

temps(i) = 0;

disp(temps);

disp(length(x(:, 1)));

plot(temps, x(:, 1:end), 'r');

grid;


end
```

My main problem is the plotting of the solution. I have difficulty creating the time vector since the step is varying. I would also like to see how I could implement `ode45` for this.

P.S I don't seem to be able to fix the formatting. You're welcome to edit.

Comment: For code, don't mangle it for Mathjax with all those ampersands and backslashes. Just copy and paste the code into your post, select the whole block of code, and then hit <ctrl>-K at the keyboard and it will be formatted in a style appropriate for code and also people trying to answer your question will then be able to copy your code directly from the question and paste it into a Matlab script.

Comment: Just build up a time vector the same you build up the `z` vector. And call `ode45(@(t,y)nagumo1(t, y, f),...` via anonymous function or use the ode options to pass the extra parameter.

Comment: @LutzL when i add the following:
 $$
 time = 0;\\
 ...\\
 (inside loop, right bove z  = [z;y])\\
 time = [time;time(i)+h]\\
 ...\\
 plot(time, x(:, 1:end))\\
$$
Then for tspan[0 50], i get a plot until time = 150 or more tspan gets greater.

Comment: Please describe in general words what you want to achieve with the algorithm. The outer loop is for fixed step size, the inner loop seems to have no influence on that. `ode45` uses an internal adaptive step size and interpolates at the times provided by the times list argument. Compare your ideas to a similar implementation for RK4 at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40866829/3088138.